# Win XP task scheduler backup

Tags: windows-xp, backup, task-scheduler

In my factory, we have two non-networked windows xp machines connected to some industrial equipment. Every day, they log the information that the equipment passes on. I've been backing them manually every month, because I can't get the task scheduler to work.

The machines are running as administrator, without passwords. When I schedule the task, usually between 12-3 AM, it simply won't start. I get a message "Task failed to start" and an error code 0x0.

I tried going to the local policy editor, and specifically added the local administrator account to the "backup files and directories" policy, but still no dice. I googled the issue, and all anyone said was try unchecking the "interact with desktop" box in the task scheduler service, but it's already unchecked. These machines were never part of a domain, so I don't think it could be a group policy issue.

Anyone ever encounter something like this?

Comment: We need more information to help you determine why your task is failing.  What exactly is the task supposed to run? A batch file? If you run the task manually, does it complete as expected?

Comment: Is there anything useful in the event viewer?

Comment: The task is suppose to run the windows backup utility. If I run the backup manually for "Right now" it works, but if I schedule it in the windows backup utility, it also fails.

Comment: Also, there is nothing relevant in the event viewer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting the `Task Scheduler` service?

1. Click Start, point to Settings, and then click Control Panel.
2. Double-click Services.
3. In the list of services, click Task Scheduler, click Stop, and then click Yes when you are prompted to stop the Task Scheduler service.
4. Click Start, and then click Close.

Comment: I tried that, no dice

Comment: @jpoopz would a 3rd party software be an option? I believe the Cobiansoft backup has it's own scheduler. It is also free and XP compatible. http://www.cobiansoft.com/cbnew.htm

Comment: They don't want any third party software installed on these other than what's already on them.

Comment: @jpoopz I just located an XP machine and tried to set up a ST that backs up. I was able to do it as Admin without a PW but it didn't run. I added a PW to the Admin account and it worked. Are you able to add a PW?

Comment: @jpoopz Are you scheduling through NTBackup itself? or through Scheduled Tasks?

Comment: @jpoopz Looks like it can't run with a blank password. Microsoft link here: http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;310715

Comment: Well, there's my answer. Thank you so much for the help!